# Looping through a JSON File - android

Tags: android, json, for-loop

I am currently making an App to order meals as part of a little task. I have a JSON file that is read when you go on the spinner to select the meal you want. But I need a for loop that can loop through the JSON file.

**JSON File**

```
[
  {
    Name: "No Meal Selected",
    SandPrice: "0.00",
    RegPrice: "0.00"
  },
  {
    Name: "OFFER (See Notes)",
    SandPrice: "3.79",
    RegPrice: "5.29"
  },
  {
    Name: "Whopper",
    SandPrice: "3.79",
    RegPrice: "5.29"
  },
  {
    Name: "Double Whopper",
    SandPrice: "4.79",
    RegPrice: "6.29"
  },
  {
    Name: "Whopper Junior",
    SandPrice: "2.19",
    RegPrice: "3.69"
  },
  {
    Name: "Whopper Bacon And Cheese",
    SandPrice: "4.59",
    RegPrice: "6.09"
  },
  {
    Name: "Angus XT Steakhouse",
    SandPrice: "5.59",
    RegPrice: "7.09 "
  },
  {
    Name: "Angus XT Classic",
    SandPrice: "5.09",
    RegPrice: "6.59 "
  },
  {
    Name: "Angus XT Smoked Bacon And Cheddar",
    SandPrice: "5.59",
    RegPrice: "7.09 "
  },
  {
    Name: "Angus Steakhouse",
    SandPrice: "4.99",
    RegPrice: "6.49 "
  },
  {
    Name: "Angus Classic",
    SandPrice: "4.49",
    RegPrice: "5.99 "
  },
  {
    Name: "Angus Smoked Bacon And Cheddar",
    SandPrice: "4.99",
    RegPrice: "6.49 "
  },
  {
    Name: "Angus Steakhouse Double",
    SandPrice: "5.99",
    RegPrice: "7.49 "
  },
  {
    Name: "Angus Classic Double",
    SandPrice: "5.49",
    RegPrice: "6.99 "
  },
  {
    Name: "Angus Smoked Bacon And Cheddar Double",
    SandPrice: "5.99",
    RegPrice: "7.49 "
  }
]


^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
JSON i need to loop through
```

If somebody could please help me it will be very Helpful,

Thank you.

Comment: post your sample json

Comment: [
{Name:"No Meal Selected",SandPrice:"0.00", RegPrice:"0.00" },
{Name:"OFFER (See Notes)",SandPrice:"3.79", RegPrice:"5.29" },
{Name:"Whopper",SandPrice:"3.79", RegPrice:"5.29" },
{Name:"Double Whopper",SandPrice:"4.79", RegPrice:"6.29"},
{Name:"Whopper Junior",SandPrice:"2.19", RegPrice:"3.69"},
{Name:"Whopper Bacon And Cheese",SandPrice:"4.59", RegPrice:"6.09"},
]
  
this is what i need the for loop to loop through

Comment: update your question

Comment: you are getting this from webservice ?

Comment: no from a file i have saved in android studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONArray items = jsonObj.getJSONArray("nameOfArray");

for(int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you provided is not properly formatted.
First, JSON file should start with an object, not an array:

```
{"Array":[*contents of your array*]}
```

Second, each object/array name should be a String - this means in quotes:

```
{
    "Name": "Angus Smoked Bacon And Cheddar",
    "SandPrice": "4.99",
    "RegPrice": "6.49"
}
```

Please refer to [The JSON Data Interchange Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) for details

Then you can use the following template to get JSON objects from an array:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONObject(myFileContents).getJSONArray("Array");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    // . . . work with object
}
```